# PHP OOP how to access class parent property Scope Resolution Operator (::)?

Tags: php, properties

How can I access property `var` in class `OtherClass` from inside class like the method `myFunc (parent::myFunc();)`

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public $var = 'A';
    protected function myFunc()
    {
        echo "MyClass::myFunc()\n";
    }
}

class OtherClass extends MyClass
{
    public $var = 'B';
    // Override parent's definition
    public function myFunc()
    {
        // But still call the parent function
        parent::myFunc();

        echo "OtherClass::myFunc()\n";
    }
}

$class = new OtherClass();
$class->myFunc();
```

Comment: dod you want to access `$var` of class `MyClass` from class `OtherClass` ?

Comment: I don't think you can unless you declare them static. Which is probably not what you want...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, because there's no separate variable. `OtherClass` extends `MyClass` therefore `OtherClass` contains all the MyClass features + additional stuff from `OtherClass` but whilte keeping access to parent's methods (thru `parent::`) makes perfect sense (i.e allows chaining) then having more than one variable of the same name would cause massive headache w/o bringing any benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Create getter and setter methods for var.

```
class MyClass
{
    private $var = 'A';

    public function getVar()
    {
        return $this->var;
    }

    public function setVar($var)
    {
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    protected function myFunc()
    {
        echo "MyClass::myFunc()\n";
    }
}
```

You can then either use `$this->getVar()` in `OtherClass` if you don't override the getters and setters there. Or if you do, you can use `parent::getVar()` from within `OtherClass`.